# Wake up from sleep by only keyboard/mouse activity Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend

When I had Ubuntu 16.04 my computer would go into some sleep state where pressing any key on the keyboard would wake it up.
Now that I have Ubuntu 18.04, it goes into this state where the power button is blinking and I have to press it to wake up. I'd like to go back to the way it was previously.

Comment: is it desktop pc or laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to  @PRATAP for help reaching this answer.

1. Install dconf-editor

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

2. Run it from terminal:

`dconf-editor`

3. Go to `settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-battery-type`. 
   Set `Use default value` to `OFF`, and `Custom value` to `blank`.

[image]

4. To get the same behavior when laptop is connected to power - go instead to 
   `settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type`, and do same as in 3.

Comment: Please mark this as an accepted answer so that people can tell at a glance that this question has an answer that worked for the asker (OP).