# How to wake system from sleep by hitting any key?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, suspend

I am using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS on a desktop. I have a wireless keyboard and generally sit away from the computer even when working on it. I have assigned a keyboard shortcut to put the computer in sleep by just hitting Super+F12. I remember when I used Windows, I could wake the system from sleep by hitting enter. Now I cannot wake my system from sleep by using the keyboard. I have to go to the CPU and press the power button to wake it up. I tried [the solution given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102081/wake-up-from-sleep-by-only-keyboard-mouse-activity-ubuntu-18-04) using `dconf-editor`. But it didn't help, because I am using Xfce and not Unity/GNOME. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: "Now I c"annot wake my system from sleep by using the keyboard. " is a BIOS function. So start there. Make sure power functions do not disable or reduce power to ports. Next: make sure you can use "sleep" (hibernate/suspend) and it is not just turning the system off (find the command line function to hibernate ;) )

Comment: `sudo systemctl hibernate` for instance or `sudo pm-hibernate`

Comment: @guiverc I have edited the question to include the version number. It is Xubuntu 20.04 with Xfce 4.14

Comment: @Rinzwind The sleep here is suspend, triggered by `systemctl suspend`, and not hibernate. Also, I have Windows in dual boot too, and I can still wake it up by hitting enter